# TOC - Horizontal Alignment

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, formatting

My currente TOC is looking like this:

[image]

And here is a code sample:

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft} %pacote para editar ToC
\usepackage{titlesec} %pacote para mudar formatacao de secoes

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries SUM\'{A}RIO\hfill} %centralizes toc title  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill} %centralizes toc title
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %places dots on sections lines as well

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{INTRODU\c{C}\~{A}O}

\subsection{SISTEMAS DE CHUTE}

\subsubsection{\bfseries chucrute}

\paragraph{\bfseries \textit{ablidebob}}

\subparagraph{\textit{abebob}}

\end{document}
```

However, my college requires everything in the TOC to be aligned to the left, like this:

[image]

But I just can't make that happen. Any suggestions?

Comment: As I suppose you use `babel`, note the `brazilian` option redefines `\contentsname` as `Sumário`, so you don't have to redefine it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macro `\cftsetindents{<X>}{<left margin>}{<title indent>}` is what you need, where `<X>` is a sectioning unit name.  In all cases, I have set the left indent to 0pt, and the title indent to 4em.

I also set `\cftdotsep` to make the dots closer, as per the OP's example.  Finally I use `\cftsetpnumwidth{1em}` to reduce the space between dots and page number.  It may need to be changed if your page count hits 3 digits.

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocloft} %pacote para editar ToC
\usepackage{titlesec} %pacote para mudar formatacao de secoes

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\titleformat*{\section}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subparagraph}{}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hfill\bfseries SUM\'{A}RIO\hfill} %centralizes toc title  
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill} %centralizes toc title
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} %places dots on sections lines as well

\cftsetindents{section}{0pt}{4em}
\cftsetindents{subsection}{0pt}{4em}
\cftsetindents{subsubsection}{0pt}{4em}
\cftsetindents{paragraph}{0pt}{4em}
\cftsetindents{subparagraph}{0pt}{4em}
\def\cftdotsep{1}
\cftsetpnumwidth{1em}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\clearpage

\section{INTRODU\c{C}\~{A}O}

\subsection{SISTEMAS DE CHUTE}

\subsubsection{\bfseries chucrute}

\paragraph{\bfseries \textit{ablidebob}}

\subparagraph{\textit{abebob}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! Thats just what I needed. I never thought it would be so simple.